# pound character(#) in asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax

iam using asp.net and asp.net-ajax
every thing happens on browser
urls are of format

```
http://somepage#page1
http://somepage#page2
http://somepage#page3
```

now all these urls are in a secured folder
when logged in user directly types (or use bookmark) a url like below, he is shown that page

```
http://somepage#page2   -- (bookmarked url lying in secured folder)
```

now when a user user who is not logged in directly type above url he gets redirected to login page
but on login page in redirection url iam unable to read characters after pound (#) sign.
iam just getting redirection url= "http://somepage" while i want it to be "http://somepage#page2"
is there is any way i can do this

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the "#" sign in a URL is never sent to the server so you won't be able to read the value from your ASPX page.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/?ref=home#/profile.php?id=100000200357449&ref=mf

this is a facebook profile url
if a user who is not logged in try to access this url he sent to login page and when he provides his credentials correctly he is again send to that url how do they read characters after pound character

Comment: They might have some JavaScript that saves it in a cookie or sets it in a query string as some encoded value. Run an HTTP trace tool like Fiddler to see how Facebook is having it sent to the server.